Has Attic Greek grammar been well-preserved enough or well-recorded enough so that it can be theoretically revived for daily communication?
Do scholars know enough about Attic Greek's grammar for us to learn to speak and write it fluently? Have enough grammar texts and records survived, and has there been a continuous line of textual interpretation and commentary such that we are sure of the meanings of Plato's and Aristotle's works?

You don’t need to know everything about the grammar of a language to revive it. There are lots of obscure verbal forms that aren’t actually attested in Greek, but which can be easily inferred from what is attested – this is similar to what happened with Hebrew. We definitely know enough about Attic Greek that it would be theoretically possible to revive it for daily use the way Hebrew was. Whether such an endeavour would be likely to be successful is another matter, of course.

To revive a language, grammar is usually not the problem, it is the surviving vocabulary. And even than, there is the need to create new vocabulary for all the things that wrent invented at Attic times (airplanes, bicycles, telephones, etc.)

This question might be a better fit for Latin SE, which also does ancient Greek.
